# Determine landscape or portrait of HTML resource at runtime on iOS

Tags: iphone, xcode, web-applications, runtime

I have an app that is essentially an eBook reader.  It is able to download a zip file that contains a group of HTML, CSS and JavaScript.  The app unzips the file and then displays the "webapp".

For 99% of the eBooks, I want the app to display in portrait only.  The pages are all formatted with this in mind. So, the app is now set for portrait only.

There is one eBook however that would work best in landscape view.

How can I detect if this eBook is loaded and change at runtime to show the pages only in landscape view?

I can easily put a string in the index.html file `<div class="youCantSeeMe">Landscape</div>` and have this div hidden.  How can I search for this string at runtime and then change the setting in the app so that this resource is only viewed in landscape mode.

Linda

Answer (score 0):

Are you using UIWebView to display that content? If you do, I assume that the HTML/CSS/Javascript do the rest of the job with the eBook.. Have you try some kind of bridge between javascript and objective C? something like [this](http://tetontech.wordpress.com/2008/08/14/calling-objective-c-from-javascript-in-an-iphone-uiwebview/).

Hope this helps

Comment: Or this one : http://www.codingventures.com/2008/12/using-uiwebview-to-render-svg-files/ .. Look for this title: "Javascript communicating back with Objective-C code"